# AppFabric ConnectionString not updated after change of Database Server Name

Tags: database-connection, app-fabric

I have used the command:

```
stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername <oldServerName> -newservername <newServerName>
```

to rename my SQL Database Server.

When I run `Get-SPServer` after a restart the correct server names appear, however when I go to `regedit SOFTWARE->Microsoft->AppFabric->Configuration`, the `connectionstring` is still pointing at the old server.

How can I update this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You should use a SQL alias instead using `cliconfg` on each SharePoint server. Use the old SQL server name as the alias and point it to the new SQL server name.

Comment: When I did with Aliases and turned the old SQL Server off SharePoint was down as it was still using the old server... we can't leave the old server on..

Comment: Your alias was set up incorrectly or you had another configuration issue, then. Aliases (or using HA like AOAG) is the only supported way to "move" the Config and Admin databases. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/move-all-databases as a reference.